# Why Iron-router does not render the correct post

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

Good morning / after noon.

this my project built with Meteor js.

I've this template(lien) for links

```
<template name="lien">
      <ul>
        <il><a href="{{pathFor 'dogo'}}">{{sousplus}}</a></il>
     </ul>
</template>
```

And another tempalte (dogo) for the post matching each link of the template above

```
<template name="dogo">
<div class="container">
{{#if hadanata3ou}}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default bttn"> ♥ </button>
{{/if}} 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <h3 id="tex"> {{submittedText}}</h3>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid lov">
<div class="row">
 {{#each positions}}
  {{> position}}
  {{/each}}
   </div>   
   </div>
</template>
```

both templates are in the same template(home) side by side

```
<template name="home">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 ">

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
         <a href="#" id="plus" class="moumi"> + </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
         <h5> create a new categorie</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      {{#each liens}}
        {{> lien}}
      {{/each}}
    </div>

</div>  

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">


   {{> dogo}}

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</template>
```

The goal is to render one and one specific template whenever a user click on one link from the template (lien); knowing that there are several links matching several template (dogo);

The deal with me is that the template rendered is the same whatever the link clicked.

And here is my Iron-router configuration

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('home');
}, {
  name: 'home'
});

Router.route('/posts/:_id', {
name: 'dogo',
data: function() { return Positions.findOne(this.params._id); }
});
```

Did I miss something? beacause it does not work with me. Could you enlighten me, please?

The concept of operation is the same as todos which the link is here [a link](http://todos.meteor.com/lists/aEFRCQPkjnhbungfo). Thank's

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong,

If you click on this

```
<li><a href="{{pathFor 'dogo'}}">{{sousplus}}</a></ll>
```

you want to redirect to `/posts/:id`

then try

```
<li><a href="{{pathFor 'dogo' data=_id}}">{{sousplus}}</a></ll>

_id is to which route you want to redirect to
```

Refer to the docs:
https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#path-and-link-template-helpers

**OR**

you could simply give

```
<li><a href="/posts/{{_id}}">{{sousplus}}</a></ll>
```

Comment: Oh thank's; I try it but it does not work for me :( ; the other issue is that it render the template dogo even if there is no link !! what I want is to render  one dogo template for each link, if there is no link, it sould render no template.